# Magento - Store View & code - 1.6.2

Tags: magento-1.6

I am currently transfering a magento site to a new server, and I am coming across this which i would like to remove:

Domain.com/gb/

the GB, i have located it in the manage store view, and have tried to disable it but when I do this the website will not render just to use that store as a default, can anyone give me a nudge?

Any questions please let me know and I will provide as much info as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies, found the answer:

**System > Config > Web > Add Store Code to URLs**

this was marked as yes, switching to no resolved this.